# Odoo 12 - TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to get mail when a new record created and modified for a field in CRM Module so i have defined this functions , someone help me with this issue

in py file :

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
        for rec in self:
            template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
            template.send_mail(rec.id, force_send=True)          
    return super(crm_extended, self).write(vals)

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    rec = super(crm_extended, self).create(vals)
    if 'opportunity_id' in vals:
        template = self.env.ref('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
        for rec in self:
            template.send_mail (rec.id, force_send=True) 
    return rec

@api.multi
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(crm_extended,self).create(vals)
    if res and res.customer_name:
        template = self.env.ref ('crm_extended.create_crm_lead_mail_template')
        template.send_mail (res.id, force_send = True)          
    return res
```

when the change the state or give save, odoo popping me an error as below

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 962, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'
```

I don't know what's wrong. When I duplicated an old record and saved, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake : You can't use `@api.multi` to odoo's create method.

You have to use `@api.model`

Comment: stll iam not getting the mail bro , i have given the date 90 day from now

Comment: That if any error doesn't come up and still mail not received it means either you have wrong config of outgoing mail server or some mistake in coding.
I suggest you to debug you code with pdb(python debugger) and check one by one line , so you can check thoroughly.